# What's the etymology of "when the sh*t hits the fan"?

Tags: etymology, idioms

Where did this come from? It makes no sense to me...why is the shit even near the fan?

Comment: You're not a father, are you?

Comment: I've often wondered if it is a variant on "When the rubber meets the road"....

Comment: @foggyone, I certainly am not a father. Could you explain?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Possible sources

[Partridge](http://books.google.fi/books?id=Nm3jbg0JalMC&pg=PA523&dq=shit%20hit%20fan%20slang&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7kcyT8CSBunl4QTZ_5STBQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=shit%20hit%20fan%20slang&f=false) says it's US and Canada slang from c. 1930, and that Norman Franklin says (1976) the original reference is to ther agricultural muck-spreader, and also mentions the following joke as perhaps valid.

The [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=shit&allowed_in_frame=0) says:

> The expression [*the shit hits the fan*] is related to, and may well derive from, an old joke. A man in a crowded bar needed to defecate but couldn't find a bathroom, so he went upstairs and used a hole in the floor. Returning, he found everyone had gone except the bartender, who was cowering behind the bar. When the man asked what had happened, the bartender replied, 'Where were you when the shit hit the fan?' [Hugh Rawson, "Wicked Words," 1989]

---

### US military in WWII

The phrase was at least part of US military slang during World War II, as  euphemistic versions can be found in contemporary books, particularly in US Marines accounts of the war. From [1945](http://books.google.fi/books?id=X8d8AAAAIAAJ&q=%22hit%20the%20fan%22%20OR%20%22hits%20the%20fan%22%20OR%20%22hitting%20the%20fan%22&dq=%22hit%20the%20fan%22%20OR%20%22hits%20the%20fan%22%20OR%20%22hitting%20the%20fan%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PkYyT_G4MrTY4QSWvv3AAQ&redir_esc=y)'s *The U. S. Marines on Iwo Jima* by Raymond Henri *et al*.

[image]

> "**The garbage hit the fan** on that one," said a captain.

The [1947](http://www.archive.org/stream/starspangledmika00kellrich#page/108/mode/2up) *Star-Spangled Mikado* by Frank Raymond Kelley says:

> In December, 1945, to borrow a line from an irreverent song 
>   popular among Americans in Tokyo "**the Shinto hit the fan**."

The song title is also shown in the [1946](http://books.google.fi/books?id=T-rOAAAAMAAJ&q=%22hit%20the%20fan%22%20OR%20%22hits%20the%20fan%22%20OR%20%22hitting%20the%20fan%22&dq=%22hit%20the%20fan%22%20OR%20%22hits%20the%20fan%22%20OR%20%22hitting%20the%20fan%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zU0yT92pJ6qm4gTBxcGqBQ&redir_esc=y) *The conqueror comes to tea: Japan under MacArthur* by John La Cerda:

[image: Shinto hit the fan]

[1949](http://books.google.fi/books?id=6BPUAAAAMAAJ&q=%22hit%20the%20fan%22%20OR%20%22hits%20the%20fan%22&dq=%22hit%20the%20fan%22%20OR%20%22hits%20the%20fan%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RUUyT7jrC-fE4gSs0YmUBQ&redir_esc=y)'s *The old breed: a history of the First Marine Division in World War II* by George McMillan tells us the phrase became so popular it was used as a code for a fight or action:

[image]
...
[image]

Finally, the first I found actually using *shit* is also from WWII in *The Naked and the Dead*, the [1948](http://books.google.fi/books?ei=R1gyT9PuKdH4sgb_wfG_BA&id=hJ8FAQAAIAAJ&dq=%22shit%20*%20fan%22&q=%22the%20fan%22#search_anchor) novel by Norman Mailer:

[image]

Comment: For those unfamiliar with it, [Shinto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinto) is a Japanese religion.

Answer (score 6):

From http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/407950.html:

> **When the shit hits the fan**
>
> **Meaning**
>
> Messy and exciting consequences
>   brought about by a previously secret
>   situation becoming public.
>
> **Origin**
>
> This expression alludes to the
>   unmissable effects of shit being
>   thrown into an electric fan. It
>   appears to have originated in the
>   1930s. I can't say better than
>   'appears' as the earliest citation of
>   it that I can find is in the 1967
>   edition of Eric Partridge's A
>   Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional
>   English:
>
> "Wait till the major hears that! Then
>   the shit'll hit the fan!"
>
> Partridge lists the phrase as
>   Canadian, circa 1930, but as he gives
>   no supporting evidence we have to go
>   by the 1967 date, although it is
>   undoubtedly earlier.
>
> Other, more polite, forms of the
>   phrase, involving eggs, pie, soup and
>   'stuff', can certainly be dated from
>   the USA the 1940s. For example, Max
>   Chennault's Up Sun, 1945:
>
> "Sounds like the stuff was about to
>   hit the fan."
>
> The Fresno Bee Republican, May 1948,
>   reported on a psychiatrists'
>   convention, under the heading See How
>   Brain Boys Also Run Wild:
>
> "However, once that opening point was
>   settled, the psychiatrists entered
>   wholly in the business of the
>   convention, which culminated, of
>   course, in the selection of officers
>   for the coming year. And that, as the
>   saying goes, was when the soup hit the
>   fan."
>
> The other versions followed soon
>   afterwards.

From http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=shit%20hits%20the%20fan:

> 1. **shit hits the fan** When things get chaotic or uncontrolable, shit has
>      hit the fan. 3,000 people were waiting
>      for the movie 7 hours before it
>      opened. When it was announced that the
>      movie would not be showing, 50 chimps
>      on motorcycles parachuted down from
>      the sky. The monkeys pulled out
>      assorted automatic assault weapons and
>      then the shit hit the fan.

Answer (score 3):

Don't try this at home they say !!!

In proper sense, I believe you can try to model the physics of the solids: the fan is a device that, by its very design is meant to move air. But it can be anything else.
In the general case of some dirty low cohesion matter it will be spread all around.  And then the clean up operation is probably going to be a lengthy and unpleasant task.  You don't want to be the one who will have to clean the mess.

In figurative sense, *when the shit hits the fan* means that there is trouble ahead and that it will be very messy.

Comment: As off-topic as ever, but the Mythbusters actually tested this "myth" and found out that it doesn't get too messy. The shit is too heavy and mostly just sticks to the fan. :p

Comment: I'd say it depends on several physical parameters with opposite influences. The speed of the fan, the speed and cohesion of the projectile, etc.  Purely theoretical guesswork on my part, I confess.

Comment: Indeed. They did decide on "plausible" for the myth, but they also went large-size with a large and very powerful fan. Sorry. No more off-topic. :)

Comment: @masarah: It may be off topic, but you simply cannot introduce such intriguing information without the appropriate [link](http://www.tvshark.com/read/?art=arc5902). :)